# No systemd in Ubuntu console for Azure VM

Tags: azure, ubuntu

I have a web app deployed on Ubuntu on Azure. Through the Azure portal I can open ssh console (in the browser) to the VM. In this console I would like to interact/investigate the state of the server using systemd commands - concretely:

```
bash% systemctl redis status
```

but I just get `systemctl` - no such command? What system management tools are available on the VM?

Comment: Just want to check are you using [Azure App service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/) or [Azure virtual Machine service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/) to host your web application on azure. If you are hosting the webapp application azure virtual machine you will be able to run the `systemctl` while connecting to VM using ssh as shown in figure https://i.imgur.com/T1UQo8c.png

Comment: Please post the exact output. It's not currently clear whether the "no such command" is produced by Bash or `systemctl` - the latter expects a verb as its first argument, not second, so it will complain `Unknown command verb redis`.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the expected results***

> While connecting SSH through VM **`systemctl`** is by default will be installed if not we have to check the below configurations

I have connected the VM through SSH

[image]

First we have to check if  **`systemd`** package is installed

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep systemd
```

[image]

If it is not installed we have to install using following command

```
sudo apt-get install systemd
```

If it is already there some packages may be missed so we have to reinstall again

```
apt-get install --reinstall systemd
```

[image]

If the package is installed even after reinstallation it does not work we have to list the full path of the files inside the package using `sudo dpkg -L systemd`
May be binary files are located  in a directory that not be included into `$PATH` variable

[image]

After installing the systemd I am able to see the packages which I have created

```
dpkg-query -S /bin/systemctl
whereis systemctl
```

[image]
I have installed the webapp into the ubuntu

```
sudo apt install redis.service
```

[image]

When I check the state of the service its active and I am able to see

```
sudo systemctl status redis
```

[image]